# Recover LVM without /etc/lvm/backup/

Tags: backup, configuration, lvm, metadata

I just thought what if I lost the LVM backup folder and I only have the HDD's belonging to my one and only Volume Group.

Here is a little summary:

```
root@ubuntu-srv:/# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  
  /dev/sda1  vg00 lvm2 a--  59,62g <59,61g

root@ubuntu-srv:/# vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree  
  vg00   1   1   0 wz--n- 59,62g <59,61g

root@ubuntu-srv:/# lvs
  LV    VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  test vg00 -wi-ao---- 16,00m
```

Because of all the metadata and the LVM label sits on all of the HDD's, technically I'm facing a possible recovery - I think.

So the first step is running the `pvck` command:

```
root@ubuntu-srv:/# pvck -v /dev/sda1

    Scanning /dev/sda1
  Found label on /dev/sda1, sector 1, type=LVM2 001
  Found text metadata area: offset=4096, size=1044480
    Found LVM2 metadata record at offset=19456, size=1536, offset2=0 size2=0
    Found LVM2 metadata record at offset=17408, size=2048, offset2=0 size2=0
```

If I correct after that I need to focus the text metadata area because it contains all the previously made metadata history. Then I convert the offset value to its hexadecimal equivalent for `hexdump`. The size remain untouched because `hexdumps -n option` need bytes.

Here is the command:

```
root@ubuntu-srv:/# hexdump -C -s 1000 -n 1044480 /dev/sda1
```

My questions:

- Are my numbers good?
- Is this the correct way to start the recovery in this kind of a situation?